# Xcode Swift Pass TextField content to website textField

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook, social-networking

Lets say I have a social network (example: http://www.icloud.com/ ). There are 2 textfields on that website: E-mail, password.

I want to make an app for the website where you can login directly from the app. On the app i have 2 text fields and a button (email, password, login). How can i pass the app's email textfield content to the email textfield of the website? Same goes for the password textfield.

You could even take FaceBook as an example. They have a website (ofc), but how does the app on the iPhone work? Is it something similar to what i said, or does it work in a completely different way?

Comment: This question is extremely low quality. StackOverflow is meant to be used by people who are facing technical issues, not for people with general product ideas who want to know how to implement X or Y. Google is your weapon of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used parse in the end: 
https://parse.com

Now parse decided it's going to stop being active from 2017.

Alternatively you can use Firebase:
https://www.firebase.com

If you know any alternative services to parse, you're welcome to write them down as a comment. ;)